# How to return an instance of a dataframe in a loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have several files that I want to use to create unique Dataframes in python. I created a class that takes each file and generates the Dataframe, but I cannot return the dataframe output (but I can print it).

For example, this structure works for me:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=x
        
        df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4]})
        self.output = df
   

y = myclass(x=1)
y.output
```

but this version does not work:

```
import pandas as pd

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=x
        
        df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4]})
        self.output = df
   
for n in range (0,5):
    y = myclass(x=n)
    y.output
```

So I tried to dynamically create and assign variables during the loop but it's not clear to me what's wrong with it:

```
import pandas as pd

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=x
        
        df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,4]})
        self.output = df

i=0
for n in range (0,5):
    i+=1
    var = 'var'+str(i)
    var = myclass(x=n)
    var.output
    print (var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `var.output`:

```
for n in range (0,5):
    var = myclass(x=f'var{n+1}')
    print(var.output)
```

Output:

```
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
```

##### if you want to be able to index then use a dictionary:

```
dfs = {}
for n in range (0,5):
    dfs[f'var{n+1}'] = myclass(x=f'var{n+1}').output

dfs['var3']
```

Output:

```
   A
0  2
1  3
2  4
```